# Hover on nested elements using SASS and BEM

Tags: svg, sass, bem

I try to use hover for button element and for SVG within button. But in here piece of code https://codepen.io/asssel/pen/wvrojOd It doesn't work for SVG. Help me how to implement it.

```css
.tag {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #1F1F1F;
  border-radius: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1F1F1F;
  background-color: white;

  &_label {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  &_remove {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &:hover, &_icon path {
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    color: white; 
    stroke: white; 
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class='tag'>
     <span class='tag_label'>default tag</span>
     <button class='tag_remove'>
        <svg class='tag_icon' width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M8.5 1.5L1.5 8.5M8.5 8.5L1.5 1.5" stroke="#404040" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I changed your CSS to plain CSS to make it work in the snippet.

I guess that the main problem is the hover effect. To change the stroke of the `<path>` your CSS selector need to start from the element that is hovered. So, replace `&_icon path` with `&:hover &_icon path`.

And then you also make sure that you use `fill` and `stroke` properties for SVG elements.

```css
.tag {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #1F1F1F;
  border-radius: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1F1F1F;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.tag_label {
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tag_icon path {
  stroke: #1F1F1F;
}

.tag_remove {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.tag:hover,
.tag:hover .tag_icon path {
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
  color: white;
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='tag'>
  <span class='tag_label'>default tag</span>
  <button class='tag_remove'>
    <svg class='tag_icon' width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M8.5 1.5L1.5 8.5M8.5 8.5L1.5 1.5" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square"/>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```